# How to properly bind cider-switch-to-repl-buffer to <C-tab>?

Tags: emacs, cider

I tried

```
(eval-after-load 'cider
  '(progn
     (define-key cider-mode-map (kbd "<C-tab>") 'cider-switch-to-repl-buffer)
     (define-key cider-repl-mode-map (kbd "<C-tab>") 'cider-switch-to-repl-buffer)))
```

But it only works in the buffer, i.e. I can switch from the buffer to the repl, but not the other way around. What I'm trying to achieve is to use <kbd>C-tab</kbd> to switch back and forth between the buffer and the repl.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you want to bind in the repl is `cider-switch-to-last-clojure-buffer`, eg

```
(with-eval-after-load "cider-mode"
  (define-key cider-repl-mode-map (kbd "<C-tab>")
    'cider-switch-to-last-clojure-buffer))
```

Comment: @damonh if you know its normal keybinding, it's even easier from the repl to just do `C-h k` `C-c C-z`

Comment: It's usually better to put the `define-key` on a mode hook (e.g. `cider-repl-mode-hook`, presumably) than to use `with-eval-after-load` to define the key. Is there some reason that that won't work here?

Comment: @Drew personally I have all my mode configs in separate files that with autoload hooks, so I imagine everyone does it differently.